# i2c devices are detected, then dissapear

Tags: i2c

I have 4 MCP23017's connected to my Raspberry Pi 4's i2c bus all with different addresses hardwired via the address pins. Upon booting up, only two of them will be detected, and after about 5 minutes, one of those two will no longer be detected, leaving me with just the one device detected.

Of note, they are all connected to the same bus, and are all powered off of the same 3.3V pin. I had originally thought it was an issue with having too many devices on one bus, but I doubt that is the issue because I've had six or seven devices on one bus before. I had the thought that a few of them might not getting enough power, but after unplugging power from one or two in any configuration (e.g. two that are not detected, the two that are initially detected, or one that is not detected and the one that is), nothing changes.

I also have a HT16K33 connected to another bus on its own set from the gpio pins, but nothing else is connected to the pi, besides the LEDs that HT16K33 is operating (they are not being powered when this issue is occuring). The issue also occurs when nothing is connected to the Pi short of the MCP's.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Well, I have been playing with MCP23017 for a couple of years.  I could once put 8 MCP23017 on one bus, but found them not stable.  Two is optimum. You might like to search my about 200 old post on the rpi.org.forum, skim the photo that matches you best, and see any clues./ to continue, ...

Comment: Or you can upload you photo here, and everybody can help. I also have a couple of tips on how to troubleshoot I2C detection on SO and EESE, and also here. Ref: Rpi.org.forum search mcp23017 tlfong01 found 178 matches - rpi.org.forum 2021apr29
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/search.php?keywords=mcp23017+tlfong01&sid=3136898ad54fde944a27ec3decf39c44. Happy troublsshooting. Cheers.

Comment: Poor wiring is the most likely reason.  Loose wires, poor connections.

Comment: @joan there’s a good chance, it’s a bit of a rats nest honestly. I was really just wondering if there were any common issues with i2c configurations like this as I have had similar issues using a TCA9548A i2c mux where I knew for sure it wasn’t a wiring issue.

Comment: @tlfong01 I would post a photo, but it wouldn’t be of much use. It’s a rats nest and you wouldn’t be able to make heads or tails of it. I’m building a chessboard and the mcp’s are running reed switches so there’s a ton of overlapping wires. I’ll check out those forum posts, thank you.

Comment: @tflong could the reset pins be causing this? I fiddled around with my wiring and realized I never connected reset to power. All four devices are stable and detected now. I’m curious as to how two of the devices would still be detected, and consistently at that, without the reset pin being powered?